# Align div vertically within parent div?

Tags: html, css

How do I position my `caption` div vertically centre within `caption-wrap`?

http://jsfiddle.net/0j5e06mt/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="caption-wrap">

    <div class="caption">
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.caption-wrap {background:red;height:120px;width:100%}
.caption {background:blue;text-align:center}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
.caption{
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Source: http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/

Comment: Don't forget the vendor prefixes to cover more browsers:
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
 -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
 transform: translateY(-50%);